# Can I safely uninstall Adobe Bridge CS5/CS6? If so, how?

Tags: adobe-bridge

It's packaged into every Adobe CS install I've ever done, and I never use it (directly?) so it's a waste of space for me. Can I kill it? (Will it cause any harm?) What's the best way to trash it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just head to the application and drag the application icon to the trash.

That will uninstall it, there is no harm to the rest of Creative Suite. (I have done this with every install of CS)